# How to align Items both left and right in same RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

Here is the XML I wrote for the Custom Row of ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#EFEFF4"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/CircleRed"
        android:id="@+id/statusColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatusName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/statusColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Customer Satisfaction"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStatusName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/Right"/>
</RelativeLayout
```

My Right Arrow of ListView Item is not getting aligned right , either it is out of the screen or its position varies depending upon length of Text of **TextView**

I need my ListView to look like this
[image]

But I am getting my row like this in Android Studio Designer.
[image]

Thanks It worked By Udpating Right Arrow XML to this.

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/Right"/>
```

Comment: In imageview which has android:src="@drawable/Right" remove android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStatusName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStatusName"` from Arrow Image view and also set `android:layout_toLefttOf="@id/imageViewRight."`

Give imageViewRight id to right arrow image view.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use linear layout instead of relative layout.Your code some what like this:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin_medium">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_driver_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:text="Hari Piorko" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_vehicle_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_driver_name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="MH-08-6789" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_vehicle_no"
            android:layout_weight="0">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_driver"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:buttonTint="@color/color_green" />

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/color_gray" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to install in device or emulator what is look alike ? Right arrow is visible or not in emulator please check it once.
 if it is not showing then try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#EFEFF4"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/statusColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatusName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/statusColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Customer Satisfaction"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

There is no need to change in code. 
Hope it helps you.